# Stacked bar chart in Seaborn

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, stacked-bar-chart

I have the following data:

```
countries2012 = [
    'Bolivia',
    'Brazil',
    'Sri Lanka',
    'Dominican Republic',
    'Indonesia',
    'Kenya',
    'Honduras',
    'Mozambique',
    'Peru',
    'Philipines',
    'India',
    'Vietnam',
    'Thailand',
    'USA',
    'World'
]

percentage2012 = [ 
    0.042780099,
    0.16599952,
    0.012373058,
    0.019171717,
    0.011868674,
    0.019239173,
    0.00000332,
    0.014455196,
    0.016006654,
    0.132970981,
    0.077940824,
    0.411752517,
    0.017986798,
    0.017361808,
    0.058076027
]

countries2013 = [
    'Bolivia',
    'Brazil',
    'Sri Lanka',
    'Dominican Republic', 
    'Indonesia', 
    'Honduras',
    'Mozambique', 
    'Peru', 
    'Philippines', 
    'India', 
    'Vietnam', 
    'Thailand', 
    'USA',
    'World'  
]

percentage2013 = [
    0.02736294,
    0.117160272, 
    0.015815952 ,
    0.018831589,
    0.020409103 ,
    0.00000000285,
    0.018876854,
    0.018998639,
    0.117221146,
    0.067991687,
    0.496110972,
    0.019309486,
    0.026880553,
    0.03503080414999993
]
```

I want to make a stacked bar plot so that there's a stacked bar for 2012 and another for 2013.

How can I go about this since the countries in 2012 and 2013 are different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, you can create a [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) dataframe and use its plot function:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame({2012:percentage2012}, index=countries2012),
                pd.DataFrame({2013:percentage2013}, index=countries2013)],
               axis=1, sort=False)

df.T.plot.bar(stacked=True, figsize=(12,6))
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Is there a simple way to have the stack in the reverse order (to get the countries in the same order top to bottom, both in the legend as in the stack)?

Comment: `df.T.iloc[::-1].plot...`?

Answer (score 45):

Since this question asked for a stacked bar chart in *Seaborn* and the accepted answer uses `pandas`, I thought I'd give an alternative approach that actually uses Seaborn.

Seaborn gives an example of a [stacked bar](https://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/part_whole_bars.html) but it's a bit hacky, plotting the total and then overlaying bars on top of it. Instead, you can actually use the histogram plot and `weights` argument.

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

# Put data in long format in a dataframe.
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'country': countries2012 + countries2013,
    'year': ['2012'] * len(countries2012) + ['2013'] * len(countries2013),
    'percentage': percentage2012 + percentage2013
})

# One liner to create a stacked bar chart.
ax = sns.histplot(df, x='year', hue='country', weights='percentage',
             multiple='stack', palette='tab20c', shrink=0.8)
ax.set_ylabel('percentage')
# Fix the legend so it's not on top of the bars.
legend = ax.get_legend()
legend.set_bbox_to_anchor((1, 1))
```

[image: seaborn stacked bar chart]