# Seaborn Barplot How to include multiple values in one bar

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, bar-chart

I got a number (lead time) on the y-axis which comes from the addition ofthree other values and i want to plot a Bar, which shows the total lead time for five different measurements on the x axis. In this bar I want it to show the three values, basically stacking them on top of each other. Is there anyway to do this with seaborn?

If this is not possible, is it possible to have the three values plotted on their own combined to one of the five x-value?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), then edit the question. Provide your minimal code, a sample input, the expected output, and how your current output differs.  From your description, I would not know what your graph is supposed to look like.

Comment: [Stacked bar chart in Seaborn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59038979/stacked-bar-chart-in-seaborn) should give some hints. Could you add some toy data and show the code you tried?

Comment: @Mr.T thanks I will use the next time I post!