# Stacked bar plot with seaborn or matplotlib, having hue

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn, stacked-bar-chart

I want to have a stacked bar chart which has the date as on X, a value on Y and a non-known number of values stacked on each other.

The table looks like that:

```
Date,Type,Value
2022-08-01,Type1,5000
2022-09-01,Type1,5500
2022-10-01,Type1,6000
2022-08-01,Type2,50000
2022-09-01,Type2,55000
2022-10-01,Type2,60000
2022-08-01,Type3,20000
2022-09-01,Type3,18000
2022-10-01,Type3,19000
```

So here, Type1, 2 and 3 would be stacked onto each other.
I have seen examples of matplotlib with stacked=True, but this does not allow *hue=Type*. On the other hand, in seaborn, I use the hue parameter for types, but it does not have a stack bar version.

What is the easiest way to achieve this?

Comment: `ax = df.pivot(index='Date', columns='Type', values='Value').plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, rot=0)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on [getup8 answer of Stacked bar chart in Seaborn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65852680) you can do that by combining `histplot` with `multiple='stack'` and [`weights=`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.histplot.html).

> **weights** : vector or key in data
>
> If provided, weight the contribution of the corresponding data points
> towards the count in each bin by these factors.

[image]

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Date': ['2022-08-01', '2022-09-01', '2022-10-01', '2022-08-01', '2022-09-01', '2022-10-01', '2022-08-01', '2022-09-01', '2022-10-01'],
    'Type': ['Type1', 'Type1', 'Type1', 'Type2', 'Type2', 'Type2', 'Type3', 'Type3', 'Type3'],
    'Value': [5000, 5500, 6000, 50000, 55000, 60000, 20000, 18000, 19000]})


ax = sns.histplot(df, x='Date', hue='Type', weights='Value', multiple='stack')
```

Comment: This looks terrible, but is actually working, thank you :D